# discord.gateway: Shard ID None has successfully RESUMED session

Tags: discord.py

While executing the function in the while loop, no error occurred, but "discord.gateway: Shard ID None has successfully RESUMED session " is displayed, and the loop execution stops. Does anyone know a solution?

```
    while True:
        response = requests.get(account_creation_date_url)
        html = response.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        titles = soup.select_one('#serverPage > div > div > div > div > div > div > span')

                #print(titles.get_text())

        await asyncio.sleep(3.0)
```